# Updating XML Tag Values using VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

I need to update below XML using VB.NET code. Tags are already added , i just need to update those with value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <LANGUAGE>ENG</LANGUAGE>
        <STATEMENT/>
        <STATEMENT2/>
        <STATEMENT3/>
        <SIZE/>
        <LANGUAGE>FRA</LANGUAGE>
        <STATEMENT/>
        <STATEMENT2/>
        <STATEMENT3/>
        <SIZE/>
        <LANGUAGE>SPA</LANGUAGE>
        <STATEMENT/>
        <STATEMENT2/>
        <STATEMENT3/>
        <SIZE/>
        <ATTRIBUTE>A</ATTRIBUTE>
        <CONTAINMENT/>
        <ATTRIBUTE>B</ATTRIBUTE>
        <CONTAINMENT/>
    </test>
```

There are no parent tags in this XML.

For ENG I need to update Statement, Statement2, and Statement3.

Same case with SPA and FRA. But the data going into those will be different. That means STATEMENT for SPA and FRA will carry different data.

I have all the related data with me, fetched in DataTable in VB.NET code, but I am unable to differentiate between the STATEMENT tag for SPA and FRA.

Is there any way that I can update the STATEMENT Tag related to SPA with different data and the STATEMENT tag related to FRA with different data?

I have already tried the GetElementsByTagName method, but it updates all of the tags with same data, and retains last entry.

Please let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: So what specifically is your problem?  Are you having trouble loading, filtering/selecting, modifying, or saving?  It sounds like your only problem is in selecting the correct elements to update, but with the way you've worded your question, that isn't entirely clear.  Perhaps if you showed some of your code it might help.  Also, do you have a preference between XPath and LINQ?  Do you care which class is used (e.g. `XDocument`, `XmlDocument`, etc.)?  There are many ways to skin this cat, so without specifying the technology, you'll end up with all sorts of different answers.

Comment: I would suggest fixing your xml schema. If the `<STATEMENT/>` belong to a particular `<LANGUAGE>`, the data should be hierarchical. That's the point of XML. But you could read the XML elements sequentially using the `XmlReader` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim XDocument1 As XDocument =
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <LANGUAGE>ENG</LANGUAGE>
            <STATEMENT/>
            <STATEMENT2/>
            <STATEMENT3/>
            <SIZE/>
            <LANGUAGE>FRA</LANGUAGE>
            <STATEMENT/>
            <STATEMENT2/>
            <STATEMENT3/>
            <SIZE/>
            <LANGUAGE>SPA</LANGUAGE>
            <STATEMENT/>
            <STATEMENT2/>
            <STATEMENT3/>
            <SIZE/>
            <ATTRIBUTE>A</ATTRIBUTE>
            <CONTAINMENT/>
            <ATTRIBUTE>B</ATTRIBUTE>
            <CONTAINMENT/>
        </test>

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To XDocument1.Descendants("LANGUAGE").Count - 1
        Dim XLanguage1 As XElement = XDocument1.Descendants("LANGUAGE").ElementAt(i)
        Dim XStatement1 As XElement = XDocument1.Descendants("STATEMENT").ElementAt(i)
        Dim XStatement2 As XElement = XDocument1.Descendants("STATEMENT2").ElementAt(i)
        Dim XStatement3 As XElement = XDocument1.Descendants("STATEMENT3").ElementAt(i)

        Select Case XLanguage1.Value
            Case "ENG"
                XStatement1.Value = "Statement1 for English"
                XStatement2.Value = "Statement2 for English"
                XStatement3.Value = "Statement3 for English"
            Case "FRA"
                XStatement1.Value = "Statement1 for French"
                XStatement2.Value = "Statement2 for French"
                XStatement3.Value = "Statement3 for French"
            Case "SPA"
                XStatement1.Value = "Statement1 for Spanish"
                XStatement2.Value = "Statement2 for Spanish"
                XStatement3.Value = "Statement3 for Spanish"
        End Select
    Next

    MsgBox(XDocument1.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi David Thanks for response. In our case we are using XMLDocument instead of Xdocument. So we are not able to use XDocument1.Descendants("LANGUAGE").ElementAt(i).  Can you please give the same code for XMLDocument.  Thanks a lot in advance !!

Comment: Try using the methodology that I have provided in your other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503677/add-parent-node-into-already-present-xml-file-using-vb-net/24518600#24518600 if you still can't achieve the desired outcome, I will provide you the solution :)