# Deleting All nodes in XML after Particular node

Tags: xml, vb.net

Hi I have an XML as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
-<Master> 
 <UserDetails>
  <UserName>Michael</UserName>
  <Password>Password</Password>
 </UserDetails>
 <Height>155</Height>
 <Weight>150lb</Weight> 
 <OtherDetails>
  <Phone>987654327</Phone>
  <Email>mich.int@ymail.com</Email>
 </UserDetails>
 <company>155</company>
 <address>155 beecroft</address>
</Master>
```

My requirement is to remove all nodes below HEIGHT `<Height>` node. No matter how many nodes are there after HEIGHT `<Height>` should be removed from XML
My final output should be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
-<Master> 
 <UserDetails>
  <UserName>Michael</UserName>
  <Password>Password</Password>
 </UserDetails>
 <Height>155</Height>
</Master>
```

Please let me know how i can do it in VB.NET.

Comment: There are several ways to work with XML in .NET. Show some codes you have tried so we can see which way you took and suggest using the same..

Comment: Please, can you show [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? We will be glad to help you in any particular problem you have while doing it, but not coding for you

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use a simple `For Each` loop and a flag, like

```
Dim remove = False
For Each node in xml.<Master>.Elements.ToList()
    If remove Then node.Remove()
    If node.Name = "Height" Then remove = True
Next
```

or a `While` loop and `NextNode()`, like

```
Dim node = xml.<Master>.<Height>(0).NextNode()
While node IsNot Nothing
    node.Remove()
    node = xml.<Master>.<Height>(0).NextNode()
End While
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way using `XmlDocument` ([in case you still use that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503677/add-parent-node-into-already-present-xml-file-using-vb-net#comment37939048_24504262)) :

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
'load your xml here'
'select all nodes next to <Height> :'
Dim tobeDeleted = doc.SelectNodes("/Master/Height/following-sibling::*")
For Each node As XmlNode In tobeDeleted
    'remove each selected node :'
    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node)
Next
```